# Want to extract string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I've string like this `[[English language|English]]`. I tried to extract text from string. But no luck. I just Want to ignore text `[[English language|`.Output should be `English`.

Another example:
`[[Stack Exchange|Question]]` Output should be only `Question`

If there is no `|`

`[[Stack Exchange]]` Then output should be only `Stack Exchange`.

I'm new to `regex`. Will you please help me ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do it.

```
^\[\[(?:.*?\|)?(.*?)?\]\]$
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?2vd3j).

The first capturing group will contain the text you want.

Comment: More useful than your example is that site, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ... wow, what a great tool!

Comment: @alex How Can i use this. I tried `re.sub(r('^\[\[(?:.*?\|)?(.*?)?\]\]$',s)`

Comment: @no_access: Access the first capturing group in Python.

Comment: @alex Please help. `import re
s = "[[English language|English]]"
re.sub('^\[\[(?:.*?\|)?(.*?)?\]\]$',s)` Getting error message.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without regex

```
>>> text="[[English language|English]]"
>>> text.strip("[]").split("|")[-1]
'English'
>>> text="[[Stack Exchange|Question]]"
>>> text.strip("[]").split("|")[-1]
'Question'
>>> text="[[Stack Exchange]]"
>>> text.strip("[]").split("|")[-1]
'Stack Exchange'
```

Note, first strip all "[" and "]" from either end and then split the string with "|" as separator. Return the last item from the list.

Using Regex

```
>>> text="[[English language|English]]"
>>> re.findall("([^\[\]\|]+)",text)[-1]
'English'
>>> text="[[Stack Exchange|Question]]"
>>> re.findall("([^\[\]\|]+)",text)[-1]
'Question'
>>> text="[[Stack Exchange]]"
>>> re.findall("([^\[\]\|]+)",text)[-1]
'Stack Exchange'
>>>
```

In case no match is found, it will generate index Error: So we can do the following modification

```
try:
   result=text.strip("[]").split("|")[-1]
except IndexError:
   None #or what ever you intend to have here
```

or

```
try:
    result=re.findall("([^\[\]\|]+)",text)[-1]
except IndexError:
   None #or what ever you intend to have here
```

Performance Comparison

```
>>> stmt1="""
import re
text="[[English language|English]]"
try:
    result=re.findall("([^\[\]\|]+)",text)[-1]
except IndexError:
    None
"""
>>> stmt2="""
text="[[English language|English]]"
try:
    result=text.strip("[]").split("|")[-1]
except IndexError:
    None
"""
>>> import timeit
>>> t1=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt1)
>>> t2=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt2)
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
4.89 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
1.43 usec/pass
>>>
```