# want to parse paragraph using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have paragraph like below.  I just Want to ignore text `[[drama film|film]]`.Output should be `film`. 
ANother example `[[Scotland|Scottish]]` output should be `Scottish`
If there no `Pipe` [[Eva Birthistle]] then output should be only `Eva Birthistle`

```
Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic [[drama film|film]]
directed by [[Ken Loach]], and starring [[Atta Yaqub]] and [[Eva Birthistle]]. The 
title is taken from a [[Scotland|Scottish]] song by [[Robert Burns]], the complete
line  being ''[[Ae Fond Kiss|Ae fond kiss]], and then we sever...'
```

`Output I want`

```
   Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic film
directed by Ken Loach, and starring Atta Yaqub and Eva Birthistle. The 
title is taken from a Scotland song by Robert Burns, the complete
line  being 'Ae Fond Kiss, and then we sever...'
```

Is it possible?

Here is [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396361/want-to-extract-string-using-regex) .I tried that solution in this. But that one is not working. I shall be very appreciate. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer to that question if the regular expression isn't working? Also, what about it isn't working?

Comment: @Wilduck That is my another problem. Which Is now working fine. With that solution.

Comment: In your sample output, `[[drama film|film]]` becomes `film`, `[[Scotland|Scottish]]` becomes `Scotland` (which doesn't match your description), and `[[Ae Fond Kiss|Ae fond kiss]]` becomes `Ae Fond Kiss`.  How do you decide whether to use the first or second element from each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solution's didn't work because your question was unclear. Here is the solution to this question

```
>>> x="Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic [[drama film|film]]\ndirected by [[Ken Loach]], and starring [[Atta Yaqub]] and [[Eva Birthistle]]. The \ntitle is taken from a [[Scotland|Scottish]] song by [[Robert Burns]], the complete\nline  being ''[[Ae Fond Kiss|Ae fond kiss]], and then we sever...'"
>>> print re.sub("([^\[\]]*\|)|(\[\[)|(\]\])","",x)
Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic film
directed by Ken Loach, and starring Atta Yaqub and Eva Birthistle. The 
title is taken from a Scottish song by Robert Burns, the complete
line  being ''Ae fond kiss, and then we sever...'
>>> x="Hero Hitler In Love is a 2011 Punjabi [[romantic]] and [[action film|action]] film directed by [[Sukhjant Dadda]] with story, screenplay & dialogues by [[Babbu Maan]]. Hero Hitler is produced by B S Maan (Khantmanpur) and [[Darshan Singh Grewal]], and stars [[Babbu Maan]], [[Mouni Roy]] and [[Bhagwant Mann]]. ''Hero Hitler In Love'' was released on 18 November in mostly all Punjab theaters. It released to mixed reviews but did have a good opening at the box office."
 >>> print re.sub("([^\[\]]*\|)|(\[\[)|(\]\])","",x)
 Hero Hitler In Love is a 2011 Punjabi romantic and action film directed by Sukhjant Dadda with story, screenplay & dialogues by Babbu Maan. Hero Hitler is produced by B S Maan (Khantmanpur) and Darshan Singh Grewal, and stars Babbu Maan, Mouni Roy and Bhagwant Mann. ''Hero Hitler In Love'' was released on 18 November in mostly all Punjab theaters. It released to mixed reviews but did have a good opening at the box office.
>>>
```

Comment: Its missing some word. Please try.  `Hero Hitler In Love is a 2011 Punjabi [[romantic]] and [[action film|action]] film directed by [[Sukhjant Dadda]] with story, screenplay & dialogues by [[Babbu Maan]]. Hero Hitler is produced by B S Maan (Khantmanpur) and [[Darshan Singh Grewal]], and stars [[Babbu Maan]], [[Mouni Roy]] and [[Bhagwant Mann]]. ''Hero Hitler In Love'' was released on 18 November in mostly all Punjab theaters. It released to mixed reviews but did have a good opening at the box office.`

Comment: Offcourse it did :-). Thanks for mentioning. I have corrected the Regex

Answer (score 0):

That other question wasn't far off:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[(?:.*?\|)?(.*?)\]\]')
>>> input = """Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic [[drama film|film]]
directed by [[Ken Loach]], and starring [[Atta Yaqub]] and [[Eva Birthistle]]. The
title is taken from a [[Scotland|Scottish]] song by [[Robert Burns]], the complete
line  being ''[[Ae Fond Kiss|Ae fond kiss]], and then we sever...'"""
>>> print(pattern.sub("\\1", input))
Ae Fond Kiss... (also known as ''Just a Kiss'') is a 2004 romantic film
directed by Ken Loach, and starring Atta Yaqub and Eva Birthistle. The
title is taken from a Scottish song by Robert Burns, the complete
line  being ''Ae fond kiss, and then we sever...'
```